# Need help troubleshooting 'Module javafx.controls not found' error when compiling and bundling MAVGCL in Ubuntu 22.04 with openJDK 17 and JavaFX 17

Tags: java, javafx, java-17

I am trying to compile this software : https://github.com/ecmnet/MAVGCL for Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. It is used to decompile ulog files (uav px4 log file).

I installed openJDK 17 as well as JavaFX 17 (I assume ...) and clone all the necessary repositories and use `ant` to compile and deploy the app.

```bash
git clone git@github.com:ecmnet/MAVGCL.git
git clone git@github.com:ecmnet/MAVBase.git
git clone git@github.com:ecmnet/mavcom.git
git clone git@github.com:ecmnet/mavutils.git
git clone git@github.com:ecmnet/mavmap.git

cd MAVGCL/MAVGCL
```

Change pom.xml of MAVGCL from this:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mavbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>mavbase</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

to this

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>MAVBase</groupId>
            <artifactId>MAVBase</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

then run

```bash
ant deploy_linux_17
```

It compiles as expected but when the compiler tries to budle it to create an App-image I got this error :

```bash
deploy_linux_17:
     [echo] Deploy JDk17 Version
     [exec] Error: Module javafx.controls not found
     [exec] java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.controls not found
     [exec]     at java.base/java.lang.module.Resolver.findFail(Resolver.java:892)
     [exec]     at java.base/java.lang.module.Resolver.resolve(Resolver.java:129)
     [exec]     at java.base/java.lang.module.Configuration.resolve(Configuration.java:420)
     [exec]     at java.base/java.lang.module.Configuration.resolve(Configuration.java:254)
     [exec]     at jdk.jlink/jdk.tools.jlink.internal.Jlink$JlinkConfiguration.resolve(Jlink.java:217)
     [exec]     at jdk.jlink/jdk.tools.jlink.internal.JlinkTask.createImageProvider(JlinkTask.java:536)
     [exec]     at jdk.jlink/jdk.tools.jlink.internal.JlinkTask.createImage(JlinkTask.java:424)
     [exec]     at jdk.jlink/jdk.tools.jlink.internal.JlinkTask.run(JlinkTask.java:276)
     [exec]     at jdk.jlink/jdk.tools.jlink.internal.Main.run(Main.java:56)
     [exec]     at jdk.jlink/jdk.tools.jlink.internal.Main.main(Main.java:34)
     [exec] Specified runtime image directory runtime-image: ./target/custom_jre does not exist
     [exec] Result: 1

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 13 seconds
```

I assume that I did not correctly installed JavaFX but I did not find any informations about how to do it (yes I did all google links ...).
Does anyone have some idea about what is going on and what should I try ?

Thanks

I tried :

- to install different version of the JDK (14, 17, 20) and install JavaFX with snap but it did not work;
- to compile the JavaFX to integrate it into the openJDK (I never did that before so I am not sure about what I actually did).

Comment: The thing [comes with JavaFX jmods](https://github.com/ecmnet/MAVGCL/tree/master/MAVGCL/jmods).  Other than that, I can't help you, I don't know what it is nor what it does, how it builds or how it works.  For a specialized project like this, it is better to ask the developers directly rather than a generic forum like StackOverflow.

Comment: I also asked the question as an issue on the github repo. But thanks for your reply !